# character disappers while using getline()

Tags: c++, getline, trie

so here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Trie.h"
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    string input;
    Trie dictionary('\0');
    while (true)
    {
        getline(cin, input);
        if (input[0] != '.')
        {
            dictionary.analyzeText(input);
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    while (input[0] != '.')
    {
        getline(cin, input);
        dictionary.analyzeTextP2(input);
    }
    system("pause>null");
}
```

It's not final version but when I enter an input such as:

```
The quick brown fox
totally jumper over
the lazy
terrier dog
.
```

The `.` in the last line should be the mark to finish getting an input from user, however `getline` doesn't get it at the fifth iteration, no idea why.
I've made sure that `textAnalyze()` function doesn't interact with the fifth line.

So, how come the `.` gets swallowed or what's causing it? (and I know I need a `break;` in the first loop, it's okay)

Comment: you need to debug your program. Inspect what `input` holds after each `getline`

Comment: @RSahu : AmitBL explicitly mentioned that in the question already.

Comment: Is the `.` followed by newline?  If it is not a line, then `getline()` will be waiting indefinitely, and you will never know the cause the loop also does not terminate - you cannot tell the difference between `getline()` "loosing" a character - which is unlikely and it simply not returning at all - much more likely .  It would have been simpler too to have just added `else{ break ;}` that to explain its omission in the text - that's just a distraction.

Comment: How is your program supposed to work? You have an endless loop at the beginning which consumes all the input. "I know I need a break", fine, so let's suppose you add the break, the point is still consumed in the first loop, what is the second loop supposed to read?

Answer (score 0):

> and I know I need a `break;` in the first loop, it's okay.

That is the source of the problem.

Let's simplify the input to just two lines:

```
The quick brown fox
.
```

After the first call to `getline`, the value of `input` is `"The quick brown fox"`.

The call `dictionary.analyzeText(input);` is executed.

After the second call to `getline`, the value of `input` is `"."`.

The call `dictionary.analyzeText(input);` is not executed.

In the next call to `getline`, `getline` returns with `failbit` set to true, the value of `input` remains unchanged.

In the next call to `getline`, `getline` returns with `failbit` set to true, the value of `input` remains unchanged.

and it goes on and on.

The value of `input` remains set to `"."` but the program never gets out of the `while` loop.

You need something like:

```
while ( getline(cin, input) && input[0] != '\0' )
{
   dictionary.analyzeText(input);
}
```

The second block of code for dealing with user input can simply be removed.

Comment: I got it! it happened because I did copy & paste.
when I enter the input manually it works fine.
thank you!

Comment: @AmitBL, how do you end the input stream when you enter the input manually?